# Mystery iron rod/how to remove?

Tags: floor

I have a 1947 pier and beam house with an L shaped iron rod through the floor in a hallway closet. It moves up and down but will not lift out completely. I thought it might control the vents under the house, but I inspected the outside of the house with it lifted and down--no change (it may have done that at some point; not anymore). I'm remodeling the closet and would like to remove it, if safe and possible. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: It could be a damper or a gas/water valve I would want to know before removing someone went to a bit of work to put flooring around this so it probably should at least be modified vs removal. I would expect a damper to rotate but who knows. I have customers remove devices and then the next summer or winter when things weren’t working correctly end up paying quite a bit because they removed something they did not understand.

Comment: Secret rod in a closet.  Probably does not do anything or opens door to treasure.  Go down and find where it goes.

Comment: Solving *the mystery* is really the only sensible way to do this. That would appear to involve a visit to the crawlspace (if not by you, then by someone else) to investigate what, if anything, this is attached to. If it's no longer functional, that's also the place from which to remove it.

Comment: When you do find the answer to what it is attached to Please post the reason. I'd really like to know. Thanks.

Comment: If this is only turned, then why was it not fully painted? Perhaps it is pushed down through the hole... which may explain why the lower section is not painted.

Comment: May be able to design into the new closet an access port, that can be covered. Cut the top off the bar and employ a socket and ratchet to turn if needed. Good time while renovating, to learn what it does

Comment: It does turn! And, usually it’s all the way down. I just pulled it up for the photo. Does not appear to control water to any part of the house—when I turned it and tried all of the faucets etc., no change. The damper idea is interesting because there used to be a chimney in the other room. It’s been covered up. Once it stops raining here I’ll venture under the house!

Comment: @Ecnerwal - sounds like you are too adventurous.  Just turn the thing off and see what isn't working!

Comment: Why guess?  Go downstairs, find the other end of this thing and post pictures and a description of what you see there.

Answer (score 0):

It  might turn the water or gas on/off to part of the house.

Most likely intended to rotate when in use.